# iPhone: UITabBar custom image doesn't work

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I use the following UITTabBar and UINavigationBar built-in code to place my own custom image on the background of Tabbar and Navigation bar. It works great in my iPhone 3.0 application. Now, i am trying to convert my iPhone 3.0 application to iOS4.0. I ran the same project in Xcode 3.2.3(for iOS 4.0) now but unable to view my custom Tabbar image in the background of Tabbar. I tried debugging it, but it is not calling to this function UITabbar at all, but the same time it calls UINavigationBar well and works. Is this function(UITabbar) not there (or) can't use in iOS 4.0?

```
@implementation UITabBar(CustomImage)

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Tabbar.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];

}

@end

@implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationBarCategory)

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"NavigationImage.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}
@end
```

Please advise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I have resolved it by adding the code below:

```
[self.tabBarController.tabBar insertSubview:[ [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tabbar.png"]] autorelease] atIndex:0];
```