# Objective-C: Custom TabBar UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have been searching for a way to customize the UIKit's UITabBarController.  I would like to change the background image and selected tint color to follow the design from our creative team.  It seems as though the background color can be altered as described here [Changing Tint / Background color of UITabBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571028/changing-tint-background-color-of-uitabbar)

However, I have not found a way to change the background to an image and the default 'blue' tint to another color.  There are many apps in the appstore which use custom tabbars like so:

http://itunes.apple.com/th/app/project-noah/id417339475?mt=8

Please help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Its not UITabbarController in this link

http://itunes.apple.com/th/app/project-noah/id417339475?mt=8

its a UIToolbar.

you can do it by creating a category for `UIToolBar`

```
@interface UIToolBar(CustomImage)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect;
@end


@implementation UIToolbar (CustomImage)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"imageToolbar.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
    [super drawRect:rect];
}
@end
```

Comment: Thank you.  Do I need to explicitly call the method drawRect?  The drawRect method is not executing automatically and the image is not showing.

Comment: i've edited the above code.. actually i forgot to put `[super drawRect:rect];` at the last of the function.

Comment: No, you dun have to call it explicitly.

Comment: Thanks Shrey, however the drawRect method is still not getting executed.  Rather than use a category, I am going to insertSubview as someone has suggested to me like so: [toolbar insertSubview:[ [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"toolbarBG.png"]] autorelease] atIndex:0];

Comment: Here is a reference to that solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501363/iphone-uitabbar-custom-image-doesnt-work